# calling methods from a chain inheritance program

Tags: inheritance, methods

I wrote a program consisting of 3 classes and a main class, the 3 classes going through inheritance chain(Employee, Teacher extends Employee, MathTeacher extends Teacher). I've constructed an ArrayList for employees.
so I'm trying to call a method from the MathTeacher class in the main class (concerning the ArrayList) but I can call nothing but the Employee class methods .
any advice?

Edit: I'm undergraduate, new to the Inheritance chapter.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By typecasting an item from the array into the MathTeacher object, you can use the methods from this class, not just those from Employee. For example:

```
((MathTeacher) arrayList.get(0)).mathTeacherMethod();
```

Comment: Ooh so typing (MathTeacher) before the arrayList gives me access to the MathTeacher class methods

Comment: Yes, because since your `ArrayList` contains `Employee` objects, Java can't be sure that any given object is `MathTeacher` until you tell it.